# Dataset or DataGrid to SQL Server Database Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which I filled with data from a `DataSet`. The `DataSet` gets the data from an Excel file, with a `OpenFileDialog`. I want to Insert this data into my SQL Server Express table. How can I do that?

Code with which I fill the `DataGrid`:

```
private void btnOpen_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openfile.DefaultExt = ".xlsx";
    openfile.Filter = "(.xlsx)|*.xlsx";

    //openfile.ShowDialog();

    var browsefile = openfile.ShowDialog();

    if (browsefile == true)
    {
        txtFilePath.Text = openfile.FileName;
        FileStream stream = File.Open(txtFilePath.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        Excel.IExcelDataReader excelReader = Excel.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;

        DataSet resultexc = excelReader.AsDataSet();
        dtGrid.ItemsSource = resultexc.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        excelReader.Close();
    }
}
```

I have seen some tutorials, but I don't understand them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You can use bulk insert (make sure table structures are same) Please refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

Comment: check .Net [SqlBulkCopy class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) if it suits your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataSet` object contains a [`Tables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.tables(v=vs.110).aspx) property.  Following the example they give within the documentation, you should be able to create [`SqlCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)s to update your SQL server tables appropriately.

This option gives a little more control over which data you insert, and provides flexibility if your source's data doesn't align with the destination as nicely as a `BULK INSERT` or `SqlBulkCopy` requires.

Comment: If I understand this completely, this helps me fill data from SQL Database to  `DataSet.Tables`. I want this inversely.

Comment: @vlaszlo my answer suggests iterating over the tables->columns->rows within the source (`DataSet`), to update or insert new data into the destination (SQL Database). You have complete control over designating source & destination~